# for loop bug, help needed to resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

i have this .click function, where i will retrieve a cookie info(which contains 3 index with multiple elements)

example for your reference on what i meant

> array= { name:"sam" surname:"tan" } { name:"jam" surname:"man" } {
>   name:"gam" surname:"wan" }

so i called out this by parsing it to a variable
then i created another new variable, and do a if, else function to filter the elements into the new array, as my .click function is to check for people modifying their name/surname and then press update button, which is why i'm listening to .click, my code are a quite a lot, so i'm only taking parts of it for reference purpose

```
$('#update').click(function(){
                        clickedProfile.surname = $("input[name=contact-surname]").val();
                        clickedProfile.name = $("input[name=contact-name]").val();
                        clickedProfile.gender = $("input[name=contact-gender]").val();
                        $("#contact-surname").text('Surname is ' + $("input[name=contact-surname]").val());
                        $("#contact-name").text('Name is ' + $("input[name=contact-name]").val());
                        $("#contact-gender").text('Gender is ' + $("input[name=contact-gender]").val());

                        var c = JSON.parse($.cookie('cookiecontact'));
                        var d = [];

                        for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
                        {
                            if(globalID == i)
                            {
                                d.push(clickedProfile); // in array, for that element it will store in the updated value
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                d.push(c[i]); // push in remaining non affected indexes into array
                            }
                        }

                        d.sort(function(a, b){
                            return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
                        });

                        $.cookie('cookiecontact', JSON.stringify(d));
                        console.log($.cookie('cookiecontact'));
                    });
```

i will be explaining on the codes for my purposes

```
clickedProfile.surname = $("input[name=contact-surname]").val();
clickedProfile.name = $("input[name=contact-name]").val();
clickedProfile.gender = $("input[name=contact-gender]").val();
```

I have a declared clickProfile on another function, which will attached a unique ID of a list of LI, so if my click is on first LI, clickProfile will be attached with a LI ID = 0, which link to array[0] elements.

so for my for loop, if a LI is clicked the if statement will run to push in the updated codes onto the elements of the index in the contacts array

then it will continue to push the rest of the indexes elements into var D if it's not matching the globalID of what i clicked.

When i refresh the page for the updated list,

example: starting is 
my main li form only shows the name value from each indexes in contacts array

sam

jam

gam

first time i try changing sam to zam it is running fine outputting

jam

gam

zam

second time i try changing zam to cam it will start acting weird outputting

cam

cam

jam

and after a 3rd try changing jam to ban it will become

ban

ban

ban

I have no idea what is causing this as it seems to change additional one indexes after each time i press update.

So far my logic for the function are

1. retrieve values from cookie(cookie has 3 preset elements string)
2. filter into a new variable, if global id == matched, put the updated
   info in that elements, while pushing in the rest of the loaded
   elements
3. sort it alphabetically
4. store into cookie
5. go to another page and back to check for updated list

i think my logic is ok so far but not sure where i'm doing wrong. Please point out my mistake thanks!

Comment: Please show your page HTML. It looks like you have duplicate inputs, but quite frankly, it is hard to figure out what is going on without the page :)

Answer (score 0):

This array sort algorithm is probably the culprit.

```
d.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
});
```

When you sort the array by name, your array index no longer matches with your globalID. Then, next time you click, the wrong item is replaced in your cookie array.

Here's a working version at http://jsfiddle.net/F8RvB/:

```
var clickedProfile = {};
var globalID = 0;
var cookieContact = [{ name:"one" ,surname:"oner", gender:"male", id:0 }, { name:"two", surname:"twoer", gender: "male", id:1 }, { name:"three", surname:"threer" , gender: "male", id:2}];

$('#update').click(function(){

clickedProfile.surname = $("input[name=contact-surname]").val();
clickedProfile.name = $("input[name=contact-name]").val();
clickedProfile.gender = $("input[name=contact-gender]").val();
clickedProfile.id = globalID;
$("#contact-surname").text('Surname is ' + $("input[name=contact-surname]").val());
$("#contact-name").text('Name is ' + $("input[name=contact-name]").val());
$("#contact-gender").text('Gender is ' + $("input[name=contact-gender]").val());

var c = cookieContact;
var d = [];

for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
{
    if(globalID == i)
    {
        d.push(clickedProfile); // in array, for that element it will store in the updated value
    }
    else
    {
        d.push(c[i]); // push in remaining non affected indexes into array
    }
}

d.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.id > b.id;
});

cookieContact = d;
console.log(cookieContact);
});
```

I removed the cookie function and just replaced it with a hard-coded array of POJOs for simplicity. Not sure why you're sorting the array...in the working sample here you can remove the sorting altogether. Otherwise, you should consider sorting when you get data OUT of the cookie to use later, or, update your globalID based on the sorted array index.

Comment: Hey! thanks for helping, i'm outside now so won't be able to go through ur code until later tonight, reason why i'm sorting is because i want to make it so that each time i refresh my list page it will re-call out the list alphabetically, 
if i didn't sort out and the initial list is like
<li>andrew</li> > jason
<li>Beth</li>
<li>Cat</li>

when i reload the page it will show it as 
<li>jason</li> which i don't want it to be so i sort the array.
<li>Beth</li>
<li>Cat</li>

each time i append, it will call out the list 1 by 1 based on my array indexes

Comment: anyway i'll try to remove my sorting functions and try to run my code to see if it really is the culprit and go through yours later, let me know if you have any other tips for me! @crickkills thanks

Comment: by right after modifying, i sort the array out by name first, then stored back into the cookie so the array will be in alphabetically order. Then when page reload, it will retrieve the data again from the cookie to append the new list of array, my id for each list is not preset, it depends on whether it got call out first or not. this is the code for the id registering on each id

Comment: this is the code for the appending 
for(var j = 0; j < c.length; j++)
      {
       console.log(j);
       $("#listview").append('<li data-name="' + c[j].name + '" + data-id="' + j + '" class="li"><a href="#">' + c[j].name + '</a></li>').listview("refresh");
      }